# Scroll TextArea to Top

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a TextArea with 20 lines. Most of the lines are behind the visible panel. When I open the panel, the TextArea is always scrolled to the button. I tested to set the TextArea scroll to be scrolled to the Top but I don't see any result:

```
TextArea dataPane = new TextArea();
dataPane.setScrollTop(0);
```

This is not working. Is there any other solution?

Comment: when are you setting the data of the TextArea and when are you adding it to your Scene? Try switching those commands around.

Comment: Please see the sscce [here](http://snipt.org/Caijf9). I do not see the behavior as you mentioned. My text area is always scrolled to the top. Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TextArea setScrollTop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496394/textarea-setscrolltop)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `dataPane.setScrollTop(0);` behind your code where you add your dataPane to your scene. Then it will work, see [TextArea setScrollTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496394/textarea-setscrolltop)